# How to use $ S=\frac{\sin\frac{n+1}{2}\alpha\sin(x+\frac{n}{2}\alpha)}{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am struggling to understand how to use the following:

> A general formula for the sum
>   $$ S=\sin x + \sin(x+\alpha) +\sin(x+2\alpha) +\dots+\sin(x+n\alpha)$$
>   is
>   $$ S=\frac{\sin\frac{n+1}{2}\alpha\sin(x+\frac{n}{2}\alpha)}{\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}$$

For example, how would I use it to solve the sum
$$S =\sin x + \sin 3x +\sin 5x + \dots + \sin 99x$$
I am struggling even to work out what to plug in to the formula.
Am I correct in thinking that n is the number of terms, which in this case would be 50?
$x$ is the angle. $\alpha$ is how the terms are growing, but i have no idea of how to assign this a value to use in the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put in $\alpha=2 x$, and then $n=49$.  The sum would then be

$$S = \frac{\sin{\left ( \frac{49+1}{2} 2 x\right)} \sin{\left ( x+\frac{49}{2} 2 x\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{2 x}{2}\right)}}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can I check I have understood correctly? If $x = 30^\circ$ then the sum would be: $$S = \frac{\sin{\left ( \frac{49+1}{2} 2 x\right)} \sin{\left ( x+\frac{49}{2} 2 x\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{2 x}{2}\right)}}$$

Comment: You really want $x=\pi/6$; formulae such as this assume that the argument of the sines are in radians.

Comment: Thank you. Can I check I have understood correctly? If $x = 30^\circ$ then the sum would be: $$S = \frac{\sin{\left ( \frac{49+1}{2}60^\circ\right)} \sin{\left ( 30^\circ+\frac{49}{2}60^\circ\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac{60^\circ}{2}\right)}}$$ $$ S= \frac{\sin(25\cdot 60^\circ)\sin(30^\circ+ \frac{49}{2}\cdot 60^\circ)}{\sin(\frac{60^\circ}{2})}$$ $$S= \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, just seen the comment about radians

Comment: @mikoyan: in this case, degrees works because the argument is proportional to $x$; but you need to be careful and always assume things are in radians in general.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I am still not getting this.

I am trying to check the formula with 
$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) + \sin 3 (\frac{\pi}{6}) + \sin 5 (\frac{\pi}{6}) $$ which equals two on my calculator.

There are three terms, so $n=3$

Substituting into the formula:
$$ S=\frac{\sin(\frac{3+1}{2}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{6})\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{6})}{ \sin \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{6}}$$ which equals $\frac{3}{2}$

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: This case is $n=2$.